# What print settings should I choose to print a booklet on indesign with 8.5x11 page size and 17X11 paper size?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Also, at home I do not have a printer that is able to print on 17X11. Is there a way to shrink the page size so my booklet prints on 8.5x11 paper, so I can have an idea of what it will look like? When I tried this, the pages printed on individual pieces of 8.5X11 paper portrait.

To clarify my primary question, I want my booklet to print exactly as it does in print preview, with two 8.5X11 pages side by side on one 17X11 paper.

Thank you!

Comment: Printing pages N-up is generally a function of the print driver, not InDesign. You may have more options if you click the `Printer` button in the InDesign print dialog window.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your first question is asking, exactly, but as for your second: In InDesign, you can use the "spreads" option in the Print > General dialog to print your pages as spreads.

[image]

Then, under Print > Setup, choose "Scale to Fit", so that it shrinks the two-page spread to fit your 8.5x11 paper.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Keep in mind that printing spreads from InDesign, you'll get reader spreads, not printer spreads. That means, if you intend to saddle stitch the booklet, the pages will be all wrong. InDesign does not print printer spreads. As mentioned above, that's generally a function of the print driver or imposition software like Quite Imposing.

Comment: there are open source options for printing a pdf in booklet form, some may require linux, (but one can freely and easily get a linux virtual machine running). Usually one creates a pdf as single pages (not spreads), and then pass that output file to the booklet software which creates a new pdf by using a different sheets size and imposing the booklet. This may not be suitable for commercial submissions.